# Programming against interfaces: When not to declare methods as interface methods?

Tags: c#, interface

I am beginning to program against interfaces and am trying to understand when it is unnecessary to declare a method on the interface.

My specific example is, I have some class

```
public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{

    public void SomeInterfaceMethod() 
    {
        if(doOtherStuff() == 1)
        {
            // do more stuff
        }

    }

    protected int doOtherStuff()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**How do I know when `doOtherStuff` should or should not be declared on the interface?**

My assumption is when the method isn't necessary for communication with other classes.  Its simply implementation detail to get the job done.

More specifically, I have a message bus.  I am trying to decide if the handler of a message should be an interface method.

Comment: @EdHeal The language is C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, semantically what *is* a `ISomeInterface`?  What does it *do*?

For example, suppose you have an interface:

```
public interface IDriveable
{
    void Drive();
}
```

You would reasonably expect anything which implements this interface to be something that you can drive.  But that could be a lot of things.

A `Car` can implement `IDriveable`.  It will also have other methods, such as methods to get in or out of the car or to fill it with gas.  Those don't make sense for something that's *just* "driveable*, they just make sense for a car.  So they belong there.  (Or perhaps on other interfaces which `Car` implements.)

It's not a technical issue, it's a question about the natural semantics of the types that you're building.  `ISomeInterface` doesn't really tell me much about what it should be expected to do, so it's a bit too contrived to use here.

If a member is applicable to the interface, put it on the interface.  If it's not, don't.  That's really all there is to it.